# Multiple Buttons and Listview

Tags: android, list, android-layout

I need to create a `layout` with three `Button` and three `ListView`,when i click on first `Button` first `Listview` should be shown in the same activity and second `button` second `ListView` so on....
How is this possible?.Can anyone help me.

Comment: Instead of three `listview` u can change the content of the `listview` while u click on the `button`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a Tab Layout? It's easy to use and you can have three tabs showing your list views, independently.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 1):

Add all of them to the same activity, then set the content of the three listviews. Add onClickListener() to each button and use View.Gone and View.Visible to control the visibility of the three ListViews. Or, like Hussain pointed out, just change the content of the single ListView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE